# What's the difference between `grubx64.efi`and `gcdx64.efi`

Tags: grub2, uefi

CentOS7 package `grub2-efi` provides two files that are very similar.

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  root  1070976 Mar 26 09:27 ./boot/efi/EFI/centos/gcdx64.efi
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  root  1070976 Mar 26 09:27 ./boot/efi/EFI/centos/grubx64.efi
```

Both files have the same size, but different checksum.

```
$ md5sum  *.efi
f6e4f93e632d72c1086caaf45cbf98ce  gcdx64.efi
8fe94009d3c5736129c69113f46ae73a  grubx64.efi
```

What's the difference between those files ?

What is the purpose of each file ?

In which case can I purge one or the other if I really need space ?

Answer (score 4):

When you read the [grub2.spec file](https://git.centos.org/blob/rpms!grub2/c695181b7bb165516116ba7c7d94805c799ae977/SPECS!grub2.spec#L345), you will notice that both files are almost identical, except the built-in grub prefix variable. in bug [1155274](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1155274), Peter Jones said:

> They differ in what grub's $prefix variable is set to ("/EFI/centos" [or "/EFI/redhat"] on grubx64.efi vs "/EFI/BOOT" in gcdx64.efi, which is copied into the boot image as grubx64.efi), but otherwise they're identical builds, and they're both signed by the same signing key.  "pesign -i  -l" will show signatures on a binary.

Also According to bug [851326](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=851326), the file *grub-cd.efi has been renamed to gcdx64.efi*. But it's not clear what's the purpose of that file.